# WPF connection to a SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

Basically what I am trying to do is run a small WPF program, where the user will select a SQL Server Compact database and my program will show them specific information from a specific table.

Where I am having trouble is the connection string, I want the user to be able to browse to the location where their database is saved, and not make them have it in the one location (if that makes sense)

I can get my program to work if I have the database in one location with a specific name, but the databases the user will want to check the information for will all have different names but all will have the same file extension

e.g. the code I have at the moment is this:

```
string Myfile = @"C:\Users\documents\visual studio 2010\debug\FILE.sdf";
SqlCeConnection localDatabaseConn = new SqlCeConnection("data base = " + Myfile +";
```

I can get the result I want when I have the file saved to a specific location with a specific name, but I want the user to be able to browse to their own file, which will have a different name and could be anywhere on their machine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to browse to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically it seems you want an [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx).

Example:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".sdf";
dlg.Filter = "Database file (.sdf)|*.sdf";

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    string Myfile = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WPF has some built-in file dialogs. The one you're looking for probably is [`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)

Usage:

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

if (dlg.ShowDialog();)
{
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Comment: so simple, thanks so much. changed my string to string Myfile = dlg.FileName; thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx). and your connection string must be  "Data Source="+YouPath and No the "Data Base"+YourPath